# Siri Kit For Home Automation App?

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, ios12, sirishortcuts

after reading the apple doc on [SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/), there are only 6 services where Siri SDK can be used. But i would like to know if there is any crack or way where i can use this in my home automation app, where the api request is sent to my server on my voice command.

> Edited 2018

Is it possible now with the release of iOS 12, [WWDC 2018](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/211/) and the new updates in Siri, Siri Shortcuts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As you have already pointed it out that there are currently only six categories which are supported by `SiriKit`. If you want to achieve something like `Siri`, you can give try to [SpeechFramework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech) introduced in iOS 10. That is not actually like SiriKit, but you can achieve your goal with some efforts and playing with the framework. [Here](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios-10-day-by-day-day-8-speech) is the very good tutorial for using `SpeechFramework`.

For the point of any crack or something, I would highly **not recommend** it as there may be chances of app disapproval from apple.

### **EDIT:**

Please check the EDIT section in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can kind-of do it with Siri Shortcuts, but it takes effort from the user.

There is no way for the *you* to create a special voice command. Only users can go into Settings > Siri Shortcuts and define a voice command to execute a shortcut you created from the Application.

Also, note that the voice command cannot have any parameters that are passed to the application. The voice command would have to execute a specific action that was defined by the application via the Shortcut. So, "Turn on light X," is a different shortcut than "Turn on light Y." The user would have to create two different voice commands.

As far as the shortcut goes, you can execute pretty much any code, so making an API call shouldn't be an issue.